# jQuery - Get path of nested list's child

Tags: jquery, list, path, get, nested

I've got the next list in my webpage:

- item1
- item2

  - superitem1

    - eliteitem1
    - eliteitem2
  - superitem3
  - superitem4
- item3
- item4

Now i want jQuery to return the full path from UL to LI

Example:
If i click **eliteitem2**
it will return: **item2/superitem1/eliteitem2**

I already tried multiple things with:

> $(this).parent().text(); <

But i can't get it to work, i don't need a function that only work for eliteitem2,
it should work for any LI and return the whole path...

```
//HTML
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li id="mapdb1">
        <a class="expandable">
            <span class="foldername one">mapdb1</span> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li id="somemap">
                <a class="expandable">
                    <span class="foldername two">somemap</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="mapdb2">
        <a class="expandable">
            <span class="foldername one">mapdb2</span> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li id="mapjeinner">
            <a class="expandable"><span class="foldername two">mapjeinner</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="anderemap">
                    <a class="expandable">
                        <span class="foldername three">anderemap</span> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="mapjeinner2">
            <a class="expandable">
                <span class="foldername two">mapjeinner2</span> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="nogmapje">
                    <a class="expandable">
                        <span class="foldername three">nogmapje</span> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li id="supermapp">
                            <a class="expandable">
                                <span class="foldername four">supermapp</span> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li id="eenhelelangemap">
                                    <a class="expandable">
                                        <span class="foldername five">eenhelelangemap</span> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>             
</ul> 






//JQUERY
$('.expandable').click(function() {
    //This is just some small thing i tried.
    //I tried alot of things but can't figure it out.
    //If i click 'supermapp'
    //path should return: 'mapdb2/mapjeinner2/nogmapje/supermapp'

    var path = $( this ).parent().html();
    console.log('path');     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M73XQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit, this answer is based on @boris's idea... should I just try to modify his answer? I'm not that experienced with this subject on SO.

However, this is my answer:

```js
$('li').click(function(e) {

    var path = [];
    var el = $(this);

    do {
        path.unshift(el.attr("id"));
        el = el.parent().closest('li');
    } while(el.length != 0);

    alert(path.join('/'));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li id="item1">item1</li>
    <li id="item2">item2
        <ul>
            <li id="superitem1">superitem1
                <ul>
                    <li id="eliteitem1">eliteitem1</li>
                    <li id="eliteitem2">eliteitem2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="superitem3">superitem3</li>
            <li id="superitem4">superitem4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="item3">item3</li>
    <li id="item4">item4</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Same JS as above - your HTML:

```js
$('.expandable').click(function(e) {

    var path = [];
    var el = $(this).closest('li');

    do {
        path.unshift(el.attr("id"));
        el = el.parent().closest('li');
    } while(el.length != 0);

    alert(path.join('/'));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li id="mapdb1">
        <a class="expandable">
            <span class="foldername one">mapdb1</span> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li id="somemap">
                <a class="expandable">
                    <span class="foldername two">somemap</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="mapdb2">
        <a class="expandable">
            <span class="foldername one">mapdb2</span> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li id="mapjeinner">
            <a class="expandable"><span class="foldername two">mapjeinner</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></a>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="anderemap">
                    <a class="expandable">
                        <span class="foldername three">anderemap</span> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="mapjeinner2">
            <a class="expandable">
                <span class="foldername two">mapjeinner2</span> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li id="nogmapje">
                    <a class="expandable">
                        <span class="foldername three">nogmapje</span> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li id="supermapp">
                            <a class="expandable">
                                <span class="foldername four">supermapp</span> 
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li id="eenhelelangemap">
                                    <a class="expandable">
                                        <span class="foldername five">eenhelelangemap</span> 
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
             </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </li>             
</ul>
```

PS: Requires jQuery ≥ 1.3.0

Comment: Yess!! This totally fixed it for me,
I'm familiar with JavaScript/PHP/C# and so on...
Only JQuery is new for me so thats why :)

Thankyou and Bors Very much!!

Comment: @user3570796 No problem. well, I was asking for your knowledge in the *console* in JavaScript, not JavaScript *itself* - as I was already aware, that you know JavaScript ;) . Infos about the console: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging - if you already knew it, just ignore this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .parent() function in succession.

E.g. if you want it to log the path on click:

```
$("#eliteitem2").click(function() {

  var path = $(this).attr("id");

  while($(this).parent() > -1) {
    path.prepend($(this).parent().attr("id")+"/");
  }

  console.log(path);
});
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I have added a fiddle with more information, this wont help or work for me, i need a function that will work at ANY li and won't matter if it's the 3th of 12th child. 

Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @user3570796 He is trying to target *any* li, no matter if it's the 3*rd* or 12th child. But he didn't test his code, and (just as any untested code from every developer) it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go up more than one parent.

ul -> li -> ul -> li

The text is in the `li`s. You clicked an `li`, the parent is the `ul` and its parent is the `li` with the text you want.

So if `clickedElement` is the `li` you clicked, you'll need to do

```
$(clickedElement).parent().parent().text();
```

To get the text of the parent and so on until you've reached the last parent.

If this doesn't help, a JSFiddle (or something similar) with more code to explain your scenario might help.

Edit: With the new code added to the question, to get the text, try:

```
$(clickedElement).parent().parent().children(".expandable").children(".foldername")
```

Comment: I think i will need to make a fiddle indeed.

It wouldn't matter how long and nested the list is.
It should always return the path and not just for that group.

Comment: I have added a fiddle you can look into.
Going up 2 parents also won't matter.
I need a function that will return always the path,
No matter if it is the 3th or 12th child.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've updated with a possible solution. Basically, up->up from one branch then down->down the other branch.